# Looping through a row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rows

I'm trying to write a VBA code whereby, for each row in a given range, if the string "Y" appears at all in a given row, then column "V" of the same row, will be populated with "Y". If no "Y" is found at all, i.e every value in the row is "N", then column "V" will be populated with "N".

Below is my code :

```
Public Sub test()
Dim lastrow as Long, i as Long, x As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to lastrow
   For x = 23 to 51
      If Cells(i,x).Value = "N" Then
        Range("V" & i).value = "N"
        Else
        Range("V" & i).Value = "Y"
      End If
   Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

For some reason, when I run this code, column "V" is populated with "N" for every row, despite there being some "Y"s in the given range.

Thanks!

Comment: Once your search text (you say `"Y"` but the code is looking for `"N"`) is found you should set the result cell (`V`) and then stop the search by exiting the loop for that row.  Otherwise, what this is effectively doing is setting `V` based on the _last cell_ in the row regardless of what may have been found in previous cells.  A better way would be to define a boolean variable, say `found`, initialized to `false` before looping through a row's cells.  If the search text is found, set `found` to `true` and exit the loop immediately.  Then _after the loop_ set `V` based on the value of `found`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That explanation makes perfect sense!

Comment: You're welcome.  Remember that on this and all questions you can vote answers up or, with sufficient reputation, down to indicate if you find them useful or not useful.  If a question of yours receives one or more answers that address your problem you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the best such answer as the solution.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CountIf()` to check the row:

```vb
Public Sub test()
    Dim i as Long, numYes As Long, ws As WorkSheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
    For i = 2 to ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
        numYes = Application.CountIf(ws.Cells(i, "W").Resize(1, 29), "Y")
        ws.Cells(i, "V").Value = IIf(numYes > 0, "Y", "N")    
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Mixing it up? The `Match` version should be more efficient `...IIf(IsNumeric(numYes),...` (`Dim numYes As Variant`). You know the drill.

Comment: Yes just trying something different….

Comment: Thanks for this! A very interesting, though intuitive solution

Answer (score 0):

### Check Matches in Row Ranges (Loop)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FlagData()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim ccrg As Range: Set ccrg = ws.Columns("W:AY") ' Check Columns Range
    Dim fcrg As Range: Set fcrg = ws.Columns("V") ' Flag Column Range
    
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim YesFound As Boolean
    
    For r = 2 To LastRow
        
        For Each cCell In ccrg.Rows(r).Cells
            If StrComp(CStr(cCell.Value), "Y", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                YesFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cCell
        
        If YesFound Then
            fcrg.Rows(r).Value = "Y"
            YesFound = False
        Else
            fcrg.Rows(r).Value = "N"
        End If
    
    Next r

    MsgBox "Data flagged.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may benefit from Rows object from a range.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("O6:R9") 'change this to your dataset

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng.Rows(i), "Y") > 0 Then
        Cells(rng.Rows(i).Row, "V") = "Y"
    Else
        Cells(rng.Rows(i).Row, "V") = "N"
    End If
Next i

Set rng = Nothing
```

[image]

Just change the line `Set rng = Range("O6:R9")` to whatever range you got your dataset and it should work.